# (VBA) Replicate "custom date" feature in userform

Tags: excel, vba, date

As shown in the attached pictures below, I am trying to replicate the custom number format feature where the user can add text strings to dates i.e. yyyy" x "mm" y "dd" z " resulting in a cell displaying 2017 x 10 y 26 z but it still behaves just like a normal date would (meaning the function box still shows 2017-10-26).

I have a user form with six textboxes, three for the date format and three for text strings (if any) (not a pretty UI, I know). I also have a seventh textbox that displays the resulting date with text as it should be displayed in the cell (by combining the content of the other textboxes).

The first problem is that I could not find any solution on the web where text string can be inserted in-between a date format. 
IsDate() / CDate() won't recognize the mix of numbers and text as a date. 
Numberformat = format(...) won't allow referencing textboxe.value or string as the origin of the format yyyy,mm,dd.

On top, I want to give the user the freedom to e.g. write just "17" instead of 2017 in the first textbox and the userform code to understand it as "yy", or, as another example, to leave the last text box empty and no text to be added at the end of the date.

Any ideas?

I can use something like this

```
Dim xDate As Date
xDate = IsDate(TextBox1.Value & "-" & TextBox3.Value & "-" &  TextBox5.Value)
```

This can then be used for

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = Formats(xDate, ....)
```

But then I have to feed it the format and somehow also the strings.

Feature

[image]

Example user form

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code.

Comment: Hmm, I tried ActiveCell.Value = CDate(TextBox7.Text) and (TextBox7.Value) ; as well as several different trial-and-error versions of ActiveCell.numberformat = format(Date[today for test purposes], TextBox1.Value [I put the string = "yyyy" instead of "2017"] & "TextBox2.Value" [string = "x"] & TextBox3.Value [string = "mm" instead of "10"] & ....) ... in the end, I got frustrated and deleted all my attempts and now I have no code on the "Apply" button : ( not super good at this VBA things haha

Comment: Please post your code in the post, not in comments. It's easier to read. Have you tried the `DateValue` function? https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datevalue.php

Comment: The date data type will not accept the format you're trying to pass. You need to store it as string and write a function to parse it as date if you need it for calculations.

Comment: (deleted previous comment due to incoherence). I tried to think of a way to use DateValue but it didn't lead my thoughts to any solution as to how to add strings to the format.

Comment: So what you are saying is that there is no easy way to achieve the feature included in Excel where one can just add text in between yyyy and mm and it will display it while still being a usable date, correct?

Comment: Add the normal date to the cell using `DateValue()` or `DateSerial()` so it will be a usable date and then format the cell. `.NumberFormat = "yyyy ""x""mm ""y""dd ""z"""`

Comment: Good, that works, but when I try to replace it with e.g. .NumberFormat = "yyyy" & TextBox2.Value & "mm " ... then it behaves really strange. When the TextBox2.Value is a string like "a" it displays it as 2017 a 10... but when the text is "b" it displays it as 2017 60 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using the DateSerial function which receives three unambiguous numbers as arguments. Assuming you named your controls accordingly:

```
DateSerial(tbxYear.Value,tbxMonth.Value,tbxDay.Value)
```

You could add a check to your year textbox:

```
If Len(tbxYear.Value) < 4 Then
    tbxYear.Value = tbxYear.Value + 2000
End If
```

Comment: That's an idea to overcome the issue with identifying the "yyyy" vs. "yy" ! Now remains the issue with getting the strings in between.

Comment: I don't understand why that is an issue, you already have the separate values for year, month and day and the strings for in-between, so what is the problem precisely?

Comment: I think his date string is being overrriden and formatted as a date instead of the string he wanted.

Comment: To put them together into a (number)format for the cell is my key problem. I can get it to display as a text, but not for it to be understood by Excel as a date in the same way the Excel feature in the picture above works. When I put the six items together, they don't form a date (or at least I don't know how they can be made to form one)

Comment: Range("A1").Value = DateSerial(tbxYear.Value,tbxMonth.Value,tbxDay.Value)

Comment: That forms a date but without the up to three text strings in between. The three strings from the above three in-between textboxes are missing.

Comment: I was assuming the cells already are properly formatted. If not, you must add the date to the cell as indicated and separately apply a new date format to the same cell.

Comment: As Kostas already wrote above. `.NumberFormat = "yyyy """ & tbxYearCharacter.Value & """mm """ & tbxMonthCharacter.Value & """dd """ & tbxDayCharacter.Value & """"`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function passing the characters from the textbox controls which will return the custom format:

```
Function CustomFormat(chars As Variant) As String

    Dim s As String
        s = "yyyy ""{0}""mm ""{1}""dd ""{2}"""

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(chars)
        s = Replace(s, "{" & i & "}", chars(i))
    Next i

    CustomFormat = s
End Function
```

To call it:

```
Sub T()
    Dim v As Variant
        v = Array("x", "y", "z") 'Change to textbox values
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = CustomFormat(v)
End Sub

'Format: yyyy "x"mm "y"dd "z"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Kostas K. and jkpieterse,

```
ActiveCell.Value = DateSerial(TextBox1.Value, TextBox3.Value, TextBox5=.Value)
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "yyyy """ & TextBox2.Value & """mm """ & TextBox4.Value & """dd """ & TextBox6.Value & """"
```

This works and I will manage to figure out the rest from here!